# Use JavaScript to create new page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am trying to write a JavaScript function that creates a new page that also has running JavaScript code. However, it doesn't seem to actually recognize the code when I do. My code is below

```
<script>
function openPrint(){
  var w = window.open(); 
  var html = '<html><head> \<script      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"\>\<\/script\> \<script\>var xml = \'<Report>......</Report>'\<\/script\> \<\script src="./js/printScript.js"\>\<\/script\> \<script src="./js/printHTML.js"\>\<\/script\> \<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/printScriptStyle.css"\></head><body></body></html>'
;  w.document.writeln(html);
}
</script
```

As you can see, the html variable has JavaScript code that I would like to run in the new page, but it doesn't appear in the "Sources" tab in the developer tools. Am I doing this right, or is this even possible? I know those two .js files work as I've used them before in other projects. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without being able to test it, my guess is that it's because you're using relative paths to `printScript.js` and `printHTML.js`. I'm not sure if you can do that because the popup window will point to `about:blank`.

Comment: Perhaps you mean [`w.document.write(html);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)?

Comment: I tried adding the full address, and still nothing. But the main thing I see is that in the debugger, when I select the page, it doesn't show any JavaScript. I only see the page JavaScript in the "Element Inspector" of the developer tools.

Comment: @Pluto What's the difference?

Comment: I hadn't read about `document.writeln()` before, never mind!

Comment: Can you try adding the elements with node manipulation? `var script = w.document.createElement('script'); script.src='absolute-path'; w.document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your backslashes were not in the right place

**You need to add backslash before:**

- same quotation marks (" ') that starts your string
- before backslash (\) that is not before space

Notice that you used backslash as closing tag "<\script>" that should be "</script>"

Also there is no use for 'writeln' function in this case.

**writeln() just add \r\n at the end of the string**

There it is, working:

```
 var w = window.open();
 var html = '<html><head> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"\>    </script> <script>var xml = \'<Report>......</Report>\'</script> <script src="./js/printScript.js"></script> <script src="./js/printHTML.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/printScriptStyle.css"></head>    <body></body></html>';
 w.document.write(html);
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused. Some of the backslashes (such as the ones in the closing script tag) should be forward slashes. I had to add some backslashes in order for the browser to not take the </script> tag in the string to mean the end of the entire script tag.

Comment: I ran into the same problem again when I took out all the backslashes you told me. The browser thinks the first </script> of the string ends the <script> in the beginning.

Comment: try copy what example end compare.